# Firebase manage download API not available

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to manage downloads from Firebase Storage using the Pause, Resume and Cancel API which is documented here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#manage_downloads

My downloads are working perfectly but I have no access to any of these functions, does anybody know how to access these?

[image]

```
var storageRef: FIRStorageReference? = nil
var pathReference: FIRStorageReference? = nil

func downloadImage(imageLocation: String) {

  let saveLocation = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: String(HelperFunctions.getDocumentsDirectory()) + "/" + imageLocation)

  storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

  pathReference = storageRef!.child(imageLocation)

  pathReference!.writeToFile(saveLocation) { (URL, error) -> Void in

}
```

Comment: Can you paste for us the complete `pathReference` initialization?

Comment: Thanks, updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cancel, pause or resume methods are for the FIRStorageDownloadTask class, which is returned by the [writeToFile method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasestorage/interface_f_i_r_storage_reference.html#method-detail) so, in your case:

`let task = pathReference!.writeToFile(saveLocatio....
task.pause()
task.cancel()
task.resume()`

Should work

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! I should've read the previous parts of the documentation I suppose :s